# Asynchronous read from database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a modal window window containing detailed information.

```
# show.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Info', player_info_path, :remote => true %>


# Controller
def player_info
    @player = Player.find(1) # ignore the hard-coding
end


# player_info.js.erb
alert(<%= @player.name %> ); # alerts 'undefined'
$("#player_info").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("detailed_info"))%>");
```

The javascript is executed but how can i get the detailed info from the controller to the javascript or can I perform a CRUD-action from the js.erb?

Comment: Can you try `alert("<%= @player.name %>");` (note the quotes!)? You should be able to access the player data using @player.attribute in your js view.

Comment: Ah, of course! I really should have figured that out myself, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, you were missing the quotes in `alert("<%= @player.name %>");`.
You have everything else set up correctly - so you can access @player attributes in your player_info.js.erb like so: `@player.attribute`.